# Cordova Universal Links works in iOS Simulator but not in dev/prod builds

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ios-universal-links

I am developing a Cordova hybrid app. I added the cordova-universal-links-plugin 1.2.1 to my project. It compiles and works fine with Android.

I went through all the setup steps for iOS located at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-universal-links-plugin-fix

As a result, the Xcode simulator works correctly and clicking on my app url (https://my-app-link.com/) inside the Xcode Simulator Messages app opens up the app inside the simulator and not Safari.

However when I compile the app using cordova:

```
cordova build ios --debug --device --no-telemetry
```

OR

```
cordova build ios --release --device --no-telemetry
```

Both of them don't work and clicking the link from the Messages app opens Safari browser instead of my app.

I already confirmed that long clicking the link doesn't show an option to "Open in MyApp". I tried different devices and it's the same.

I am suspecting that the entitlement file is not being compiled correctly when I build the project but I don't know the correct location for it in a cordova app and how to confirm if this is the problem or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it turns out to be a problem with Cordova/Phonegap build process. Once I used Xcode build process by selecting a destination of "Generic iOS Device" and then selecting Archive from the Product menu, XCode built the right IPA file and I uploaded the file to the App Store where it got the universal links working correctly on iOS devices.